# Boost program options take input after program has started

Tags: c++, boost

I am using boost program options to take command line input. That works great. But I want to be able to continue to receive input once I have run the initial command.

```
int main (int argc, char** argv) {

    boost::program_options::options_description desc("Allowed options");
    desc.add_options()
        ("help", "produce help message")
    ;
    boost::program_options::variables_map vm;
    boost::program_options::notify(vm);

    while (1) {

    try {
        boost::program_options::store(boost::program_options::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);

        if (vm.count("help")) {
            cout << desc << endl;

            vm.clear();
        }

    catch (const boost::program_options::error &ex) {
            cerr << ex.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

Currently this just keeps looping over once I run the program with the --help option. I want it to take the input once and then clear the map and be able to freshly receive new input. vm.clear() does not do the job and I don't know how else to clear it. Do I need to clear argc and argv?

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: Not sure if you are looking for a feature not supported in boost program options that cli11 calls subcommands: [https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11#subcommands](https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11#subcommands)

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "freshly receive new input". From where? From standard input? Or do you want to process the command line again?

Comment: @user23573 Standard input is fine

Comment: @user2007843, then I guess you are expecting the wrong thing from `boost::program_options` which is for "commandline arguments processing". If you want to receive from standard input afterwards, you need to **start reading** from standard input afterwards.